# How to group on a join table with custom columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQL and I seem to be stuck on something that should rather be simple.

Let's say I have two tables with the following information:

Utilisation:

| Date | User | Metric1 | Metric2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-20 | John Doe | 200 | 400 |
| 2021-07-20 | XYZ | 100 | 180 |
| 2021-07-20 | ABC | 20 | 600 |

Raw_Data

| Date | Account | Item_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-20 10:30:00 | XYZ | 1 |
| 2021-07-20 11:31:00 | XYZ | 2 |
| 2021-07-20 12:30:00 | John Doe | 3 |
| 2021-07-20 13:30:00 | John Doe | 4 |
| 2021-07-20 14:30:00 | ABC | 5 |

What I'm trying to achieve here, is to join these two to display count of Item_ID for a given day for the employee:

| Date | User | Metric1 | Metric2 | Counter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-20 | John Doe | 200 | 400 | 2 |
| 2021-07-20 | XYZ | 100 | 180 | 2 |
| 2021-07-20 | ABC | 20 | 600 | 1 |

Sadly, the below kicks back with the following error:

> column Raw_Data.Date is invalid in the select list because it is not
> contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Here's the query I tried:

```sql
select
util.*,
count(rd.Item_ID) as Counter

from Utilisation util
join Raw_Data rd
on util.Date = cast(rd.Date as date)
where util.Date>='2021-07-19'

group by util.Date, util.User;
```

My major suspicions are that either I'm trying a wrong join type or that the group part kills the result, however I can't find the solution.

Comment: All fields must be either grouped or aggregated. Replace your `select *..` with `select field1, field2...` and group by all non-aggregated fields.

Comment: Do you not need to include Account in your join?

Comment: @SMor updated the query, didn't change the result though.

Comment: Nevermind, I'm stupid - it worked after I grouped by everything that was non-aggregated. Thanks, @Arvo!

Answer (score 0):

This is simple join. Try this

Table and data script for those who want to try

```
create table #Utilisation([Date] date,  [User] varchar(30),     Metric1 int, Metric2 int)
insert into #Utilisation values('2021-07-20',   'John Doe', 200,    400),('2021-07-20', 'XYZ',  100,    180),('2021-07-20', 'ABC',  20, 600)

create table #Raw_Data ([Date] datetime,    Account varchar(30), Item_ID int)
insert into #Raw_Data values ('2021-07-20 10:30:00',    'XYZ',  1),('2021-07-20 11:31:00',  'XYZ',  2),('2021-07-20 12:30:00',  'John Doe', 3),('2021-07-20 13:30:00',  'John Doe', 4), ('2021-07-20 14:30:00', 'ABC',  5)
```

Solution script

```
SELECT U.[Date], U.[User], U.Metric1, U.Metric2, R.Counter
FROM #Utilisation U
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT CONVERT(DATE, [DATE])[date], Account, Count(Item_ID)counter
    FROM #Raw_Data
    group by CONVERT(DATE, [DATE]), Account
) R ON U.Date = R.date AND U.[User] = R.Account
```

If you want all records from Utilization table in case raw_data table does not contain any data for that dat and account then use left outer join instead of inner join.

Answer (score 0):

A simple method is a correlated subquery:

```
select u.*,
       (select count(*)
        from Raw_Data rw
        where rw.account = u.user and
              rw.date >= u.date and
              rw.date < dateadd(day, u.date, 1)
       ) as cnt
from utilisation u
where u.date = '2021-07-20'
```

For performance, you might want an index on `Row_Data(account, date)`.